# Are Google App Engine Quotas enough?

Tags: google-app-engine, bandwidth

I was thinking about giving a try with google app engine.

As such I was just reviewing the quotas/limitation the service has.

Although google states:

> All applications can use up to 1 GB of storage and enough CPU and
>   bandwidth to support an efficient app serving around 5 million page
>   views a month, absolutely free.

The request quotas seem rather low, with only 1GB Outgoing bandwidth in the Requests limits is that enough?...or am I not interpreting correctly?

http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Requests

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It sounds like your question should be... "Are Google App Engine's **FREE** Quotas 'enough.' The limits you are describing only apply to App Engine's Free Default limit.

For example... for requests, the billable limit is 14,400 GB per day maximum, with a maximum request rate of 10 GB/minute. There is no Incoming Bandwidth limit when billing is enabled.

I think the question you should ask yourself is "what type of application do I want to build." If you have application requirements that you think will exceed the default free tier, then you should plan your budget accordingly.

Comment: Does incoming requests stands for data that is sent to the server? like a client uploading information?
Thanks for the response

Comment: Yes, but each incoming request must be under 32Mb. See: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas.html#Requests

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the things you want to do with Googles App Engine. You have 1 GB Outgoing Bandwidth each day. So you have 30 GB each month (Amazon gives you for their AWS even 15 GB free outgoing traffic each month).

For private normal usages I never reached the limits. But it is hard to say what is "normal".

Comment: Is the 1GB outgoing is unique per GAE project or total of the account?

Comment: It's per project / application.  Check out https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas for more details.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very late answer but I think you (did) misunderstand.

With App Engine you get 1 GB of free bandwidth **per day.** Meaning 30 GB free per month

With 30 GB of free bandwidth Google stats that you can serve "around 5 million page views a month".

**Let's do the math:**
30 GB = 31457280 KB
31457280 / 5000000 = 6.29 KB
To provide 5 million page view on 30 GB monthly your page will need to be as little as 6.29 KB.
Maybe Google was speaking about a small REST API compressed over gzip.
Or, maybe they tried to impress use with a big "5 million".

Average web page is [around 1246 KB](http://www.webperformancetoday.com/2013/06/05/web-page-growth-2010-2013/).
31457280 / 1246 = 25246
So on a average web server you will be able to provide 25246 page monthly (in the best case)

Comment: You are not taking client-side caching into account. 6.29kb of non-cacheable content is still an extreme best case scenario, but it's not that far from reality on a site with text content that's being used by only a handful of users. Not that 1MB/page view is impossible on a content-heavy website, but it's far from typical for somebody hosting their site on the free tier of GAE.

Comment: @gbs good catch. Indeed, I didn't think about client-side caching.

Comment: Is the 1GB outgoing is unique per GAE project or total of the account?